# Insert spacing between columns in a table

Tags: python, matplotlib, datatable

I have a table plotted in a figure, using data from a csv file, that looks like this:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
spec2 = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=3, figure=fig  )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0, 1])
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')

table_data=[
["Ni_Tot ", "NN", "2.5%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.025),3)],
["N. of Samples", count,  "5%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.05),3)],
["Minimum", round(min(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "25%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.25),3)],
["Maximum", round(max(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "Median", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.5),3)],
["Average", round(statistics.mean(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3),"75%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.75),3)],
["Variance", round(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].var(),2), "95%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.95),3)],
["Std Deviation", round(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].std(),2),"97.5%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.975),3)],]

table_data2=[
    ["Ni_Tot ", "OK", "2.5%" , round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.025),3)],
    ["N. of Samples", count,  "5%" , round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.05),3)],
    ["Minimum", round(min(df['OK_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "25%" , round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.25),3)],
    ["Maximum", round(max(df['OK_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "Median", round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.5),3)],
    ["Average", round(statistics.mean(df['OK_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3),"75%", round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.75),3)],
    ["Variance", round(df['OK_Ni_Tot'].var(),2), "95%", round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.95),3)],
    ["Std Deviation", round(df['OK_Ni_Tot'].std(),2),"97.5%", round(df.OK_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.975),3)],
]

table = ax1.table(cellText=table_data, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
table.set_fontsize(14)
table.scale(1.5,1.4)


table2 = ax2.table(cellText=table_data2, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
table2.set_fontsize(14)
table2.scale(1.5,1.4)
```

And I need to add a little bit of spacing between the tables' columns (like the image). Is there any way I could do this without creating other tables?

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshot how it looks like and mockup what you want to see?

Comment: Just posted it! :)

Comment: I looked at GridSpec and it can tweak margins but looks like they are global and not per cell/column